# How to write a method to delete notes from a ide?

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

The proposed code intends to use the interface of a note taking application to delete all notes. However, upon writing this solution, the method DeleteAllNotes() does not return a code value for the Note Repository DeleteAllNotes() method.

```
    public Note DeleteAllNotes(int Id)
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      string sql = $@"DELETE all Notes where id = {Id}";
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
      {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }
    }
```

It should run a code where one can drop an entire table of data in rows or column when they are executed.

References:

1)Explanation of CS1061 Error: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061

2) Methods in C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods

3) Static Class Members in C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

4) Abstract and Sealed Class Members: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members

References: Microsoft Official Documentation.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Change `public Note` to `public void`

Comment: Please use parameterized queries. Building queries through string concatenation opens you up to the possibility of SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your method should return something or just delete data ?

Comment: @dymanoid: How do you return the Delete All notes() that allow the method to exist?

Comment: @HristoKolev: Sure I will work on that.

Comment: @Daniel Mann: Will consider that in writing the queries to make them parametrized format to reduce sql injections.

Comment: @DespeiL: It should delete data that are made using microsoft sequel server management studio in a table of data values.

Comment: So make your method void as @Daniel Mann  suggest.

`public void DeleteAllNotes (int Id)`

Comment: @DespeiL: Yes it did work. Messed up the interface with the void property.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the code you provided does not compile because of writing errors or missing items impossible to interpret. Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code, screen images and scenario diagrams. To help you improve the content, title and tags of your query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* which is in the help center.

Comment: I like the references part and "microsoft sequel server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a *record* given by its `Id` from `Notes` table

```
//DONE:  We delete, that why we return bool (has items actually been deleted), note Note
//TODO: if connStr is static, declare DeleteAllNotes as static as well 
public bool DeleteAllNotes(int Id) {
  //DONE: Syntax: correct one is "Delete From table Where condition(s)" 
  //DONE: SQL Parametrized; do not hardcode parameters - "{Id}"
  string sql =
     @"delete 
         from Notes 
        where id = @prm_id";

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
    conn.Open();

    //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id;

      return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
    }
  }
}
```